# Golang post request to NodeJS API gets stuck on formidable

Tags: node.js, express, go, formidable

For some reason, my post requests made in go with below code gets stuck on my express api using `express-formidable`. I tried removing the use of formidable in the api `app.use(formidable())` and it worked perfectly. What could cause this? It did complain about no `content-type` header but added it. After that it just doesn't go through formidable middleware (no errors logged tho).

Also tried to do the request with Insomnia. It didn't seem to work with the body in, but without the JSON body it worked fine

My post request:

```golang
func main() {

    httpClient := &http.Client{} // Create http client

    values := map[string]string{"keycode": "2345 yy"}
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(values)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "url", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    res, reqErr := httpClient.Do(req)

    if reqErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(reqErr)
        return
    }

    log.Fatal(res)
}
```

Comment: Did you try the same request with `curl` or something else ?

Comment: Yeah i tested the endpoint with Insomnia. Worked fine

Edit: NO actually. I forgot to add the body to the request. Adding the body makes it get stuck on the formidable

Comment: Could be because of default user agent used by insomnia, could you try `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"keycode": "2345 yy"}' <url>` ?

Comment: That does not work either

Comment: I am not familiar with formidable, but since insomnia request came through try adding `User-Agent` header.

Comment: It didn't. I edited my comment but i guess it went under the radar. Adding the body to the request got it stuck. I just forgot to add it the first time i tested it :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem myself!

I used also `express.json()` middleware which apparently messed with formidable. Removing that solved the problem.

Comment: Next time please try to do some debugging before asking for help. It was clearly server side issue.